# Setting value of dropdown box in url or setting $_POST variables in url

Tags: php, html, url

I have a java programme that reads values from a webpage(not host by myself). The webpage has a dropdown box which sets the value for which page is displayed. No matter which option I select the url never changes so i cannot access these pages from my programme.

This is the url http://results.shannonsportsit.ie/results.php?rally=TF14

About 7 lines down there is a dropdown box with a label "results to" from here you can choose from 5 different options{Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, finish}.

Is there any way to set this values of the dropdown box in the url or can anyone come up with any way of setting the value of this dropdown box. Or can it be done with php ie something like (http://results.shannonsportsit.ie/results.php?rally=TF14&stage=1)

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Is the dropdown a form element ?

Comment: Yes its a part of a form

Comment: Yes, it is a form with `post` method. What are you trying to achieve? You can easily past it to the url if it is get method. For `post` it is more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it is a form with post method. I want to be able to access each page from my java application dynamically, but when I change the the value in the dropdown box the url stays the same so I am unable to access these pages.

Comment: If you want to access it with java, you should tag this question with java. There should be a way to send post request from a java application. Furthermore, you have no control over the php page.

Comment: The application uses the url so I dont need any java help its php help i need if its possible. I need the url for each page in the dropdown box. This is not possible so?

Comment: I don't think so. The `each page` you mentioned is only a single page that is `results.php` that process the request from the browser. The output will depend on the `post` values from the form that get passed to it. Really, it is only a single page that creates dynamic output.

Answer (score 0):

You can create get requests using ajax like this to the page results.php

script

```
function sortResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","results.php?rally=TF14&stage="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html

```
    <form>
    <select name="sortby" onchange="sortResult(this.value)">
                <option value="1">Stage 1</option>
                <option value="2">Stage 2</option>
                <option value="3">Stage 3</option>
                <option value="4">Stage 4</option>
                <option value="5">finish</option>
    </select>
    </form>
<br>
<div id="result"><b>Results will be listed here.</b></div>
```